# PHP Traverse JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON output that looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"QID":"Q1234","MgrQID":"5678","NTID":"blah"}]}
```

I am trying to access just the data within the square brackets, inside the data array?

I have tried `$jsonVar['data']` and `$jsonVar->data` and neither of them are working.

Is there a way I can just get access to `[{"QID":"Q1234","MgrQID":"5678","NTID":"blah"}]`?

Comment: json_decode($jsonVar)['data'] ?

Comment: @MacBooc - got this `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`from trying your suggestion.

Comment: use `json_decode($jsonVar, true)`  and use as an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<?php
$data = '{"data":[{"QID":"Q1234","MgrQID":"5678","NTID":"blah"}]}';
$test = json_decode($data, true);
echo json_encode($test['data']);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
[{"QID":"Q1234","MgrQID":"5678","NTID":"blah"}]
```